# go to last activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have RoomActivity and GameActivity. RoomActivity listen server commands. Server can send 2 commands: openGameActivity and closeGameActivity. **This commands must to run only in RoomActivity**. First command I do so (RoomActivity class):

```
if(request == "open")
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

But I have problem with second command.

```
if(request == "close")
{
    //What I must do here to return back to RoomActivity?
}
```

Structure:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/asE6S.png]

**Upd**
About finish();
I cant's use it because it's static method:
RoomActivity:

```
GameActivity.finishAct();
```

GameActivity:

```
public static void finishAct()
{

    //this.onBackPressed();
    finish();//<====Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method finish() from the type Activity

}
```

Comment: just call finish() or use the flag CLEAR_TOP for your intent

Comment: intent.addFlag(FLAG_CLEAR_TOP); or somethind like this, you will find it on the flags of your intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just end your `Activity` by calling:

```
finish();
```

Comment: Keep a reference to the activity and call activity.finish();

Comment: no need to the activity , it's is just : YourActivityName.this.finish(); will do the work

Comment: RoomClass:
GameActivity.this.finish();
>No enclosing instance of the type GameActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: Apparently you don't understand the keyword static. Please read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: hm? So I use "static" to can use GameActivity functions/variables not just localy.

Answer (score 0):

call [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely review your code to set finishAct to nonstatic. It doesn't make sense to declare and use a method like that. It's also not like Activities are intended to be implemented

Comment: But how to use unstatic method?

Comment: You'll have to change methods/fields declarations as well. `static` exists for a specific set of reasons, none of which you have. If you provide your entire code, we'll review it together. Maybe you have those static methods because you don't know where to keep a reference to your Activity. If it's the case you have different options: either modify some constructor to accept an `Activity` parameter (like View) or use an Intent or a singleton pattern for your Activity. But without the code...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are implementing these "Commands" as you haven't provided any code, but if you're not already I'd suggest using BroadcastIntent's from your service. Register the GameActivity to listen for the close broadcast and the RoomActivity for the open game broadcast.

You register BroadcastReceiver's in the onResume() method of an activity and unregister it onPause().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

As other's have said, once the GameActivity receives the close broadcast it could simply call finish() on itself.